# No Metro-style app template in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a Metro-style app following this guide for a "hello, word" application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx

But I don't have any Metro-style app template when creating a new project in Visual Studio 2012 RC (Ultimate). I got my version of it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#groups

I've read that I'm supposed to be prompted to acquire a Dev License on first startup, but I never was prompted. I've also read that I'm supposed to be able to acquire one through Projects > Store otherwise, but the Store item isn't in my project menu.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need a different version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only get the Metro development bits if VS2012 is installed on Windows 8.

Comment: I have installed VS2012 on Windows 7 and performed an upgrade to win8. Can I install it separately?